# Routing php using .htaccess

Tags: url-routing

My folder structure:

```
--root
-----includes
-----content.php
-----index.php
-----sitemap.php
-----rss.php
```

i want using .htaccess file for routing my web application look like this:

```
http://mysite.domain/ => index.php
http://mysite.domain/any-slug/ => content.php
http://mysite.domain/sitemap.xml => sitemap.php
http://mysite.domain/any-slug.rss => rss.php
```

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php
RewriteRule ^(.+).rss$ rss.php?slug=$1
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ content.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But, it not working. Somebody can help me?

Comment: What is it doing wrong?

Comment: All the request was returned index.php or content.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've solved the problem but the .htaccess file just reroutes all the requests to index.php. From there you need to employ a router in order to show different pages depending on the url submitted.

For example:

1. User visits localhost/home/index/hello.
2. This gets redirected to index.php.
3. index.php uses $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to retrieve the /home/index/hello explode it and require in the right page.